# Algorithm to find the optimal group of compatible elements

Tags: java, algorithm, grouping, combinations, combinatorics

I have a set of entities and I need to group this entities in groups called `specie`. The set of all species defined calls `Universe` and an entity must belong to one and only one specie. For this I have a boolean intransitive function called `f` that returns if two entities, passed by parameters, are compatible. A `specie` is defined by a group of entities compatibles with each other and a `universe` is defined by a group of species that are not entirely compatibles with each other, assuming that the compatibility of two species is defined by the compatibility of all of it's entities.

How can I determine the universe that contains the smallest number of species possible for a given set of entities?

I tried as follows and my function returns a valid universe but not the one with the smallest number of species possible.

```
public class Specie {
    private List<Entity> individuals;

    public Specie() {
        this.individuals = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean matches(Entity e) {
        for (Entity s : this.individuals) {
            if (!f(s, e)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void add(Entity i) {
        this.individuals.add(i);
    }
}

private static int numberOfSpeciesRecursive(List<Entity> entities, List<Specie> universe) {
    if (entities.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        List<Entity> remains = new ArrayList<>();
        Specie specie = new Specie();
        for (Entity e : entities) {
            if (specie.matches(e)) {
                specie.add(e);
            } else {
                remains.add(e);
            }
        }
        universe.add(specie);
        return 1 + numberOfSpeciesRecursive(remains, universe);
    }
}
```

Comment: btw: Singular of species is species. Specie is a completely different word.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution is `O(n^3)` and mine is `O(n^4)`. If performance is a problem for you I might think of a faster way to compute it.

Comment: Can you provide what is the input and what is the output. And what should be the complexity.

Comment: Unfortunately, my solution was wrong. It seems that this problem is harder than I though. I think it is NP-hard, so the only possible exact algorithm will be exponential...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the entities as vertices of a graph, and add edges between vertices if the entities are compatible.

In this resulting graph, your definition of a species corresponds to the definition of a [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)).

Therefore the problem of finding the minimum number of species is equivalent to covering the graph with the smallest number of cliques.  This problem is known as [minimum clique cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover_problem) and is NP-complete.

Comment: Which is also equivalent to Graph Colouring, if you turn every edge into a non-edge and vice versa.  (I mention this in case someone wants to find a solver implementation...)